# Line-breaking algorithm

Tags: c#, c++, text, formatting, line-breaks

Where can I find an efficient algorithm for breaking lines of text for formatted display?

Comment: For monospaced fonts it would be pretty simple, but I'm guessing it's not what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this very problem is addressed in the book [Introduction to Algorithms](http://www.introductiontoalgorithms.com) (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein) as [problem 15-2](http://fyad.org/zm50).

It takes the approach that a nicely broken block of text has as even spacing at the end as possible, punishing large differences.

This problem is solvable using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Programming).

Naturally this is only one approach to the problem, but in my opinion it at least looks better than the greedy algorithm.

I'm not much for putting my solutions to textbook problems on the Internet, so I'll leave it to you to either solve it or Google for a solution, in order to get the exact algorithm needed.

Comment: So your way of answering this question is to point the reader to a book that doesn't contain the answer to the posted question and then say the reader should work it out himself or Google for a solution to know how it's done? That's not exactly very helpful. People come to Stack Overflow looking for answers, not looking for someone to tell them "search for it on Google".